# temporarily disable all events in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do you temporarily disable all events in javascript?  We want to make them disabled, so that some events don't run until after 700 miliseconds after we click something.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're trying to temporarily disable all clicks, then a simple way to do that without changing any of the rest of your page or code is to put up a transparent div absolutely positioned over the whole page that intercepts and stops propagation of all click events.  Then, use a setTimeout() to remove that transparent div at whatever time interval you want.

Put the blockDiv in your page HTML so it's already there.

In your HMTL:

```
<body>
    <div id="blockDiv"></div>
    ... other page HTML here
</body>
```

Then, have this CSS in the page:

```
#blockDiv {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

And, this javacript:

```
$("#blockDiv").click(function(e) {
    // stop propagation and prevent default by returning false
    return false;
});

setTimeout(function() {
    $("#blockDiv").remove();
}, 700);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a setTimeout

```
$('a').click(function( e ){

   e.preventDefault();

    setTimeout(function(){
        // DO SOMETHING AFTER 700ms
    },700);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

`setTimeout` is what you want.

> The setTimeout() method calls a function or evaluates an expression after a specified number of milliseconds.

it takes two parameters: 
 1) the function or code to call and
 2) the number of milliseconds to wait before executing the code/function.

```
 setTimeout(function(){
    //do your stuff
 },700);
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this artical, this will show to How to listen lazily to rapidly firing events

```
$.fn.bindDelayEvent = function(eventName, delay, fnc){
        $this = $(this);

        var timer = undefined;
        var delayFnc = function(){
            clearTimeout(timer);
            var self = this;
            var args = arguments;
            timer = setTimeout(function(){
                fnc.apply(self, args);
            }, delay);
        }
        $this.bind(eventName, delayFnc);

    }

    $(window).bindDelayEvent("resize", 1000, function () {
        alert("click event fires after 1000ms")
    });
```

[How to listen lazily to rapidly firing events like window resize?](http://jqfaq.com/how-to-listen-lazily-to-rapidly-firing-events-like-window-resize/)

Answer (score 1):

Disabling all events on the page is very easy. Hard part is to restore them when needed.

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML;
```

This will effectively remove all events bound to DOM nodes by replacing the DOM with it's "virgin" copy.

Most of the time user won't even notice the redraw.

As far as restoring them after a period of time, you can experiment with saving a copy of DOM before replacing the innerHTML:

```
oOldDom = document.cloneNode(1);
```

and restoring it later on.

Comment: Only if you do it in a loop. Things like disabling all events if ever needed, is done on some user action, so it is done once it is not noticeable for the eye.